# Discrete variables as part of the inputs to a Neural Network

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, data-transformation, discrete-data

I think it's best to formulate the question as an example.

Let's say I want to predict the room temperature using a simple LSTM(+dense layers etc; doesn't matter what the architecture is) model. For inputs, I choose variables that are relevant to the estimation process. Usually, in literature, people tend to use temperature at t-1, outside weather temperature, and finally the temperature setpoint. The last variable tends to remain constant for an arbitrary duration of time but changes depending on the comfort preference of the occupant. As such it raises the question how to ensure that the LSTM model gives importance to that particular variable in deciding the temperature at the next time instant. Usually for similar situations, people tend to use categorical variables but that would not work here as the possible values for this input are countably infinite.

So, is there any standard way in which researchers have tackled this problem in literature?